# Laptop typing a1z instead of 1 and s2x instead of 2

Tags: keyboard

i have a dell laptop but it has a strange problem in the keyboard. Whenever i type 1 , it types a1z and when i type type 2 , it types s2x and so on. Basically all the number keys are not working except 5 and 6.

Fixes I have tried:

Removed and connected the keyboard to motherboard.

Replaced new Keyboard (same problem in both keyboards).

USB Keyboard works but its not practical.

Installed fresh windows and also installed ubuntu.

Please help.

Comment: You should test for a swollen battery by undoing all the case screws [or loosening battery/lid/ etc as appropriate] & see if it stops.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried opening it and trying it. It still did not work.

Comment: It's a short or track issue. The keys you mention are usually on the same electrical track [they run diagonally top to bottom usually, so it's physically damaged somewhere] You can either free it up if it's under pressure, or get a new keyboard.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried a new keyboard as well, it had the same problem.  Is the motherboard shorted somewhere? or is the keyboard shorted?

Comment: Then it may be a short in the ribbon connector.

Comment: is there any way to check for this short? all number keys except 5 and 6 dont work. @Tetsujin

Comment: Perhaps, if you have patience & a multimeter, otherwise just swap it out.

Answer (score 2):

> Fixes I have tried: Removed and connected the keyboard to motherboard.
> Replaced new Keyboard (same problem in both keyboards). USB Keyboard
> works but its not practical. Installed fresh windows and also
> installed ubuntu.

USB Keyboard works and Windows reinstalled means there is a hardware error.  Cable, connector, motherboard error related to the cable.

Run a complete set of Dell Hardware Diagnostics and also contact Dell Support.

For an older laptop, contact a local repair shop.

Finally, it may be time for replacing the laptop.

Comment: Hardware diagnostics works fine. Also its a older laptop (8 year old).

Comment: Contact Dell Support or take to a local repair shop for tests.

Comment: Local repair guy suggested a motherboard swap. But its a old laptop so its not possible.